# "high" vs. "tall"

Tags: word-choice

[image: Chimney]

1. The chimney in the picture above is more than 20m ***high***.
2. The chimney in the picture above is more than 20m ***tall***.

Are both *high* and *tall* proper in these sentences?

If not, why not? And when should one prefer *high* over *tall*, and vice versa?

Answer (score 16):

I would have to disagree with @FumbleFingers.  This may be a US vs. UK thing (I'm American), but I think that it sounds odd when he describes a mountain as being "high."  I would definitely say that a mountain is "tall."  If you want to use Google hits as a metric, I found these results:
"highest mountain" 412,000 results
"tallest mountain" 755,000 results

As a basic rule, I would say if both the top and bottom of something are far from the ground, then it is high (e.g. a branch in a tree is high).  If the top is high and the bottom is low, then I would describe it as tall (e.g. the tree itself is tall).

Addendum: after much discussion, the major take-away for an English Language Learner is that nobody is going to question your English proficiency based on your choice of "tall" vs. "high" in this context.  We can debate until the cows come home, but either word is perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: Agreed...mostly.  :)  Around here, "tall" implies not just how far up the top is, but how far the top is *from the bottom*.  "High" to me means "far from the ground" in most cases, and i'd generally only use it as a synonym for "tall" for short things.  (VA, USA)

Comment: Australian here. Agreed. Continuing  @cHao's point, you can say "Tallest mountain", and "Highest point of the mountain".

Comment: Doesn't the song go "ain't no mountain *high* enough" ...?

Comment: Artistic licence, perhaps? On the other hand, this concept does confuse even native speakers, sometimes.

Comment: Are we using different versions of Google? On Google Internet, I get 921,000 hits for ["tallest mountain"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tallest+mountain%22&aq=f&oq=%22tallest+mountain%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.40636147&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and 4,980,000 for ["highest mountain"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22highest+mountain%22&aq=f&oq=%22highest+mountain%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.40666684&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). In Google Books it's even more marked, with tallest=28,400; highest=352,000.

Comment: On that subject, see [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&lpg=PA402&ots=7bu8R9Iljr&dq=merriam-webster%20usage%20high%20tall&hl=ja&pg=PA401#v=onepage&q=merriam-webster%20usage%20high%20tall&f=false) (down at the bottom of the page).

Comment: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/google-result-counts-are-a-meaningless-metric.html

Comment: As regards any possible UK/US distinction, [these usage figures](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+tall+mountain%2Ca+high+mountain&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) from Google Books suggest *a high mountain* is over 10 times more common than *a tall mountain* with the American corpus. Okay, so it's nearly 20 times more common in the British corpus - the fact remains, mountains are much more likely to be *high* than *tall* on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just repeated the search for "tallest mountain" and "highest mountain" out of curiosity (after reading snailplane's 2nd link), and although this search again put tallest ahead of highest, the numbers were not close to either your prior results or mine, so I agree that we should stop using Google hits as a metric.  Your nGrams are definitely more convincing, however, I'm afraid they may be skewed.  Anything on a mountain would be described as high: highest mountain peak, highest mountain resort, highest mountain village, etc.

Comment: @Yes I use MUMPS: I certainly agree Google counts have to be taken with a *huge* pinch of salt. I use Google's Chrome browser, and whenever I post Internet search results on ELU I always do it using their "incognito" mode, so the results aren't skewed by Google analysing my own personal usage. I cannot for the life of me explain why, but when I click on my own "highest mountain" link above, it now reports 6,120,000 results (but I know I actually cut&pasted the previous figure of 4,980,000). I can't believe our searches here could affect Google's "guestimate" algorithms that much, that quickly!

Comment: COCA (US English) says: "highest mountain" 124, "tallest mountain" 65; "high mountain" 142, "tall mountain" 12.

Comment: Love the 'major takeaway for ELL' part. Native speakers may not be aware but that's _extremely_ valuable for language learners.

Answer (score 8):

Both are acceptable, but I'm sure *high* would be more common. People tend to use *tall* in reference to objects of *human* scale; a 200-foot chimney stack is only marginally within that category. Thus:

> [Everest is 29,nnn feet high](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everest%20is%22%20high&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22everest%20is%22%20%2229%22%20%22feet%20high%22&oq=%22everest%20is%22%20%2229%22%20%22feet%20high%22&gs_l=serp.3...37122.39753.2.41390.5.5.0.0.0.0.51.214.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.-d_Vcn-LPDU&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 154 hits in Google Books
>    [Everest is 29,nnn feet tall](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everest%20is%22%20high&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22everest%20is%22%20%2229%22%20%22feet%20tall%22&oq=%22everest%20is%22%20%2229%22%20%22feet%20tall%22&gs_l=serp.3...115311.116893.4.117422.8.0.8.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.MLiwOH7kZRc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 34 hits.
>
> [Everest is the highest [mountain]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everest%20is%22%20high&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22everest%20is%20the%20highest%22&oq=%22everest%20is%20the%20highest%22&gs_l=serp.3...47702.53651.5.53939.29.24.0.0.0.4.100.1237.23j1.24.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.EsNQA3IxfpM&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 14,700 hits
>    [Everest is the tallest [mountain]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everest%20is%22%20high&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22everest%20is%20the%20tallest%22&oq=%22everest%20is%20the%20tallest%22&gs_l=serp.3...3188.6210.6.6649.14.14.0.0.0.1.131.880.13j1.14.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.QhXwZ5eUjE8&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 2,050 hits

As Jim correctly comments, you can often interpret *high* as a reference to the "elevation" of something (i.e. - distance above ground/sea level), whereas *tall* is usually a reference to the "length" of something in its vertical plane.

---

Not directly involved here, but worth pointing out, is that *because of* that connection between *tall* and the human scale/shape, we also tend to use *tall* for "rod-shaped" things perpendicularly oriented, and *high* for things with a more "extended" top surface. Thus:

> [[The] wall is six feet high](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everest%20is%22%20high&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22wall%20is%20six%20feet%20high%22&oq=%22wall%20is%20six%20feet%20high%22&gs_l=serp.3...3175.4255.10.4732.6.6.0.0.0.0.68.312.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.3g4cRG1D83Y&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 1,260 hits
>    [[The] wall is six feet tall](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everest%20is%22%20high&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22wall%20is%20six%20feet%20tall%22&oq=%22wall%20is%20six%20feet%20tall%22&gs_l=serp.3...4162.6330.11.6743.8.8.0.0.0.1.165.554.6j2.8.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.p9-FZbc82eQ&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 2 hits

Comment: Mauna Kea is taller than Everest, but Everest is higher than Mauna Kea.

Comment: @Andrew: Apparently so, if we measure mountain height/tallness as the vertical distance from [some nearby ocean floor](http://geology.com/records/highest-mountain-in-the-world.shtml) to the mountain summit. But what a meaningless way to measure elevation!

Answer (score 2):

For chimneys (like the one in the photo), towers, skyscrapers, trees, people  and anything else you can think whose height is purely vertical, native speakers will tend to prefer: **tall**.
For mountains, buildings that are wide as well as tall, walls, women heels, and for ground use **high**.

- The [**leaning tower of Pisa**](http://www.leaningtowerofpisa.net/leaning-tower-of-pisa-facts.html) is only 55.86 meters **tall**
- I am **taller** than my sister.

but

- Six-inch **high** heel shoes
- A [**high-rise building**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_with_the_most_high-rise_buildings)

However, look at how both adjectives are used here. And yet fully acceptable.

- The world's [**tallest tree**](http://www.npr.org/blogs/krulwich/2011/04/08/135206497/the-worlds-tallest-tree-is-hiding-somewhere-in-california) is hiding somewhere in California. (...) It's 369 feet **high**

Why did the writer prefer **369 feet high** instead of **tall**? To avoid repetition? Because when measuring the distance from the ground, the word high just sounded
better or perhaps more authoritative? I don't know! :)

Answer (score 1):

They would both be correct here. The main difference is that *tall* always refers to the height of something (its size), whereas *high* (while used this way for structures), can be (and often is) used to describe the elevation of something.

Comment: I take it by *elevation* you mean relative to some reference height (normally, *sea-level*). If it's just the elevation relative to the nearest ground level, that would be it's *height, tallness, vertical size* anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the original question, I think both are fine. (I'm Irish BTW.) But here's something to consider when to use "high" and when to use "tall". Imagine there is a small town with a big hill. At the bottom of this hill is a ten-story building. Every other building is a two-story building. And one of these two-story buildings sits at the top of the hill looking down on the ten-story building. In this example, I would say the building at the bottom of the hill is the tallest building in the town but the building at the top of the hill is the highest building in the town. Using this logic, I would say that it is more appropriate to say the building is tall but for a mountain, it doesn't really matter. The thing is, though, that logic and English don't always get along.

Answer (score 0):

Tall is generally for when you are measuring the distance from the ground. 
High is generally used when you don't really care about the exact distance from the ground. 
However, I liked the answer above with rod vs. flat-shaped objects. There is something to that.