# Differences between "long", "tall", and "high"

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, word-difference

What are the differences between "long", "tall", and "high"?

Do they have the same meaning and the same usage or not??

e.g "The bridge is the longest in the world." Can I use "tallest" instead of "longest" or not?

e.g "The drinks were served in tall glasses." How about this sentence?

Comment: See also: [high vs. tall](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/high-vs-tall)  (could be a duplicate)

Comment: Please tell us which dictionaries you consulted (to research the meanings) and the reason why you've decided to ask us - that is, why they're inadequate.

Comment: Most of the time I use longman

Comment: Please include the definitions you found and write about how they confuse you. _[Here’s how to keep your questions from getting closed](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)._

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Long* is generally used for a horizontal measure (something that is parallel to the ground or other surface); it is how far away one side or end of an object is from the other side or end.

*Tall* is a vertical measure; it generally means how far away the bottom of an object is from the top of that object.

*High* can be used as an informal synonym for *tall*, but in more technical usage, it is a measure of how far away from a surface the bottom of an object is, rather than how far away the top is from the bottom:  A man who is 8 feet *tall* is larger than any other human currently known, but a man who is 8 feet *high* is probably just an ordinary man who is standing on top of a ladder (so his feet are 8 feet away from the ground).

If you want to know what is the *longest*, the *tallest*, and the *highest* bridge in the world, you can certainly use all three words, but you will get a different answer for each:

- the longest bridge in the world is the Danyang-Kushan Grand bridge, which is 164 kilometers from the start of the bridge to the end (that is, the distance you will travel without ever being approximately at ground level, or having the road surface be built directly on the ground).
- the tallest bridge in the world is the Millau Viaduct in France, measuring 343 meters from the base of its lowest pylon to the top of its highest pylon.
- the highest bridge in the world is the Sidu River bridge, whose deck (the surface upon which people travel) is 496 meters above the lowest point in the gorge that it traverses.

<sub>(all bridge information taken from [wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org) searches.)</sub>

Comment: I'll add to this excellent answer that "long" is often used in generic measurement queries where the others are not. e.g. "How long is the game?" (generic measurement of time), and "How long is that desk/phone/field?" (generic measurement of length).

Comment: Note that "tall" is only ever used for overall height, while "high" can be used for any elevation.  You can ask either how *tall* a building is or how *high* it is, but you can only ask how *high* the twenty-third floor is, not how *tall* it is.

Comment: @Mark I disagree, though you might not get the answer you *expected*. If I asked how tall the 23rd floor was, I'd expect an answer stating the distance from the flooring to the ceiling of that level.

Answer (score 0):

For people : tall as in "How tall are you? I am 1.72 cm tall etc."

For things : long as in "her hair is long. (NOT tall)"

Long' suggests 'horizontally' rather than 'vertically'

For what?.. : high as in "Mount Everest is the highest mountain in the world."